# Perform task every N hours

Tags: flask

I'm using Youtube's API to pull a list of videos, and I'm updating my database with the videos' IDs. If I wanted to do this every 6 hours, what would be the best way to go about this?

Would using `@app.before_request` be an ideal solution?

```
@app.before_request
def check():
    last_updated = Table.query.first().last_updated
    diff = datetime.utcnow() - last_updated
    if dif > ...:
        ...
```

This solution, the database would get queried on every request though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The before_request decorator allows us to create a function that will run before each request. But the part is that you should run the API or request every 6 hours , So there should be some service running to pick the function every six hours and do what ever you need in our case , we are updating the Video ids in the database .

So the below example demonstrate a simple schedular , The schedular is the library which runs to pick the function every n min ir hours which we mention as part of the option.

when you run this file basically , It would execute the function "say_hello" every 5 minutes.

```
import schedule
import urlparse

def get_video_id():
  url_data = urlparse.urlparse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UF8uR6Z6KLc")
  query = urlparse.parse_qs(url_data.query)
  video = query["v"][0]
  print(video)

schedule.every(6).hours.do(get_video_id)
```

Comment: Awesome, it looks like `schedule` is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Also, it looks like you modified the code after you wrote your text - "5 minutes" should be changed to "6 hours".